# JSPM loading the same dependency from different two sources - npm:angular-material depends on github:bower-angular

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-material, jspm

I have an Angular 1.5.5 project that uses `jspm` to fetch and bundle all front-end dependencies - `angular`, `angular-material`, `angular-adal`, `ngcomponentrouter` etc.

We're resolving all of these dependencies using the `npm:` endpoint. The issue arises when we install `angular-material`, as it pulls in 2nd dependency on `angular` from `github:angular/bower-angular` (instead of `npm:angular`).

This can be replicated by running:

```
jspm install npm:angular
jspm install npm:angular-material
```

Of which the 2nd command outputs:

```
     Looking up npm:angular-material
     Updating registry cache...
     Downloading npm:angular-material@1.1.0-rc4-master-06e7e99
     Looking up github:angular/bower-angular
     Looking up github:angular/bower-angular-messages
     Looking up github:systemjs/plugin-css
     Looking up github:angular/bower-angular-animate
     Looking up github:angular/bower-angular-aria
ok   Installed github:angular/bower-angular-messages@^1.5.3 (1.5.5)
ok   Installed github:angular/bower-angular@^1.5.3 (1.5.5)
ok   Installed github:angular/bower-angular-aria@^1.5.3 (1.5.5)
ok   Installed github:angular/bower-angular-animate@^1.5.3 (1.5.5)
```

Resulting in angular being loaded twice by our UI - once from `wwwroot/lib/github/angular` and once from `wwwroot/lib/npm/angular@1.5.5`

**My question is this:**

Is there any way to force the same `angular` dependency to be resolved from only one source? How can I ensure that only a single dependency of angular 1.5.5 is loaded?

Comment: just install angular-material, angular will be installed automatically as one of its dependencies.

Comment: Two problems with that: firstly I need to be able to reference angular directly, not as a sub-dependency. Secondly, other npm libraries I use depend on npm:angular. Your recommendation makes sense, but would not solve the problem in my case.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve it?
I will try to find a way to override and map bower-angular to angular in systemjs packages configuration.

Comment: I didn't find a resolution - we switched to other frameworks shortly afterwards. Things have moved quickly in the year since I posted this question!